# Eradicate a cockroach infestation

Tags: cleaning, kitchen, pest-control

A cockroach infestation has formed in my house a while ago, probably because food was left out and dishes were never done. However for the last few months I have made sure to keep the place clean and have even used a bug bomb (the thing that looks like fly spray, but you leave it on in your house for a few hours) but there still just as many if not more cockroachs now. I can't afford an exterminator. How can I find and eradicate this cockroach infestation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mix a bag of flower, a box of sugar, and a box of borax together in a large bowl.  Cover the infected area, probably your kitchen, and all nearby flat areas including the floor with the powder and **do not** touch the powder for at least 10 days. Also set out lots of glue traps against walls and in corners.

You will begin to notice that roaches are crawling around in the powder and then dying.  They are eating the sugar and simultaneously being poisoned by the borax.  The flour helps it to stick to them.  Just let them lay there, do not sweep them up for at least ten days.  After ten days you should notice that the glue traps are filled with roaches of all sizes and there are countless baby to medium roaches dead in the powder.

Sweep up the powder and then **immediately** get a few cans of caulk and caulk **every single crack** that you can find in your entire house. This will take a long time but it must be done or else they will just re infest.  After the caulk has dried spray all seams between walls and the floor with raid daily for at least two weeks.

At this point you should notice significantly less if not no roaches.  As long as you keep your house clean, i.e. do dishes immediately after using them, wipe up bathroom if it is wet after a shower, dont leave out food **ever**, etc. then you should be good.

I apologize for the gratuitous bolded text but this is incredibly important, I have waged all out war with roaches for extended periods of time.  I have won some and lost some but I have slowly crafted this method and it has never failed me. I know it is an inconvenience especially the powder and not touching it because it basically means that area is off limit.  I would suggest to cover the entire kitchen and either eat out for two weeks or have a very thin path to the microwave or fridge that you can use to travel.

A few notes:

- Roaches love water. They love it. Never leave anything wet
- Roaches are tiny.  They can get through basically any crack
- Roaches swarm.  They are notorious for being incredibly persistent because they reproduce and swarm so quickly
- Roaches are widespread. It is likely that if you are infested then so are your neighbors I would suggest talking to them to learn more about the situation
- Roaches must die.  If you ever to see one after this process, it must immediately be killed, preferably with raid in case any other roaches are around

*Good luck bud*

Comment: If you have pets, and can not afford professional help, this still sounds like good advice, but then you have to let your pet stay at friends or a kennel during the cleanout to not risk harming your pet.

Comment: Borax is NOT recommended if you have pets or young children nearby. Keep borax as inaccessible as possible to prevent the material from being tracked, carried, or dislodged into uncontaminated areas of your home. You must still find a way to clean it up effectively after the extermination. Don't use a vacuum cleaner, for example. Read the instructions and the warnings before you bring home a container of this stuff as you shouldn't casually discard the excess.