# How to permanently banish cockroaches from the house without using any pesticide & not affecting my dog?

Tags: pest-control

These days cockroaches have plundered my house! Cockroaches always hailed in my house but they hardly bothered; two or three could be found under the sink or at the attic. But they have multiplied at a mammoth rate recently! Huge numbers of nymphs roam on the table at the verandah at night; things went worst when today I saw many nymphs floating on the drinking water I stored in a pan. Even they don't spare the fridge!! I kept my chipps & cakes at the fridge but was at the blues when I saw cockroaches already enjoying the snacks!! I have used pesticide(spray); yes it killed many but was only temporarily successful. On the 5th or 6th day, I could again see cockroaches. And recently(day before yesterday), I again sprayed on the table at verandah & at the morning I saw many nymphs dead but yesterday I saw with disgust they were resurrected again:( I am very dubious of the effectiveness on the spray; moreover I don't want to use such things as I have a pet dog; he always licks his paw &  pesticide might stick on his paw; he has his drinking-water outside & though I cover it before spraying, it still gets contaminated. I don't want my dog to get die in the course of removing cockroaches. So, is there any "*natural trick"* or any means that permanently help me get rid of these cockroaches unlike spray & also not harm my dog??

Edit: I can't afford for *professional experts*; after all there is no such thing or  such service at our state. I'm living in a small state of India.

Comment: I've seen [Eradicate a cockroach infestation](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/4309/eradicate-a-cockroach-infestation); mine can't be called duplicate because the answer that was provided there doesn't fit my requirement as borax is toxic for dogs & it may kill my dog & I don't want that; such restrictions "DO NOT touch the powder for at least 10 days" can't be imposed on my dog; he roams here & there always & I also have to go to school & hence can't take care of avoiding him to go there  :(

Comment: Even though you have a dog, the question is a duplicate with a slight variation. When that is said, that variation might need to be temporarily moved away when dealing with the roaches. In other words, I do believe you either have to get professional help (which you decline to economics), or to use the related question, with the addition that you need to let your dog stay at friends (or similar) for at least 10 days.

Comment: @holroy: it's not easy to bell the cat:( Not due to my financial setup but there is no such service in my state; I don't think anyone could have understood my predicament:((

Comment: And it's not easy to get rid of cockroaches either. So you have to choose: Move pets out of the way temporarily, or keep on living with the cockroaches. Sometimes there is no middle way in life, and you need to take the neccessary step to deal with the problems at hand. I believe this is one of those.

Comment: @holroy: Yes, this is the hard truth but one thing can you tell: why didn't the spray work?The expiry date is still a one-year later:?

Comment: Most likely, you didn't spray enough areas, or the roaches had some hard to reach areas from where they spawned. This is why the other post suggests a multiple step approach to get rid of the roaches.

Comment: @holroy:Thanks, sir & I'll not bother you but can you tell where these pests generally live so that I can spray effectively? I've sprayed under the fridge, at the table, under the sofas, at the toilet & bathrooms, at the holes under the old doors of the attic etc. Moreover, I want to tell you that I live upstairs; shall I've to apply spray downwards also?? Thanks for responding:)

Comment: Maybe the cockroaches are the dogs pets? He might miss them - will he get therapy?

Comment: @Ed Heal; A good one; you think like my sis!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried sticky traps ? This is how I got rid of them.

There is no pesticides involved and it's pretty cheap.

Like the traps [here](http://www.jjpest.com/cockroaches/).

You can also do it yourself : see this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T93YOc9_tg8)

As to where you could find it : I couldn't find it on amazon.in , but maybe some sellers on amazon.com can ship it to India.

However, I found it easily when I was living in Asia, right next to the insects repellents. It's a pretty standard item I think, but you may have to go to bigger stores.

Comment: That is pretty nice! Just I've to fetch it; can it be found at Amazon(India)??

Comment: I've added some details to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend getting professional help. An exterminator will have pet-safe products and many will guarantee results. In other words, they come back for free until the problem is solved.

There's no trick to keeping the bugs out except for methodically killing each bug, each nest, each roachie little thought needs to be killed.

Fact is you could empty your house and light it on fire. When the fire department leaves the roaches will be back. Get a pro.

Answer (score 0):

Cockroaches tend to appear either when rain is near or when rain has just stopped. With that in mind, maybe your house or some places in your house are a bit too humid. Try opening windows. Another suggestion is simply to seal any unwanted crevices or openings in your house and clean profoundly. Have everything organized and don't leave things lying around. Use rat traps to help aid in killing the roaches, especially young ones.

Comment: Regarding cleaning issue, the sink is always clean; kitchen remains clean & yes the doors of my basement & bathroom do have holes, but I weekly apply spray there; I have hardly seen any roach there; only ants live there:|  The infestation is mostly at the verandah at night. But my verandah always remains open, sunlight comes & I always clean the floor with phenyl. So, I'm not conceiving what to do:(